# Adding a second shower head from 1/2" PEX

Tags: plumbing, pex

I want to add a second shower head in our shower. Ideally both heads would be controlled by their own temperature and pressure valves.

I do not want to run any new lines from the manifold however. We have a dedicated hot and cold (1/2 PEX) running to the shower right now. Our water pressure  into the house is pretty good (about 120PSI).

My questions are:

Can I tee into the existing 1/2 inch PEX lines and run it to the new shower head and valve?

How much would this affect the water pressure and would you recommend this?

Comment: Would you be running both heads at the same time? What kind of shower heads are these? What kind of water heater do you have?

Comment: Hi Jim,  Yes both heads would need to be able to run at the same time. I'm not sure if I want to do 2 separate temp valves or just a diverter valve yet but first I just want to know I will be okay tapping into the 1/2 pex already in the bathroom to run the additional head? I know it varies based on water pressure, etc. but just wondering if this is something that is even done? And I'm also trying to figure out what the calculation is to determine what our water pressure may be roughly at each head. Any ideas?

Comment: and as far as water heater...i'm not too concerned about that aspect as it seems to hold up just fine when master and guest shower run at same time